# Sending attachment in email function but not able to get it

Tags: php, email

I am using this function for attaching pdf in my mail. It's working fine but when the user tries to open the pdf file he gets a message telling him that file can't be opened, because of a problem with file formate.

```
// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
        $separator = md5(time());

        // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
        $eol = "\r\n";

        // attachment name
        $filename = $invoice.'.pdf';

        // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($filename));
        //$attachment = $filename;

        // main header
        $from     = "test@productionserver.in";
        $headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol;

        // no more headers after this, we start the body! //
        $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;


        // message
        $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= $message.$eol;

        // attachment
        $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= $attachment.$eol;
        $body .= "--".$separator."--";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Does anyone have an idea what I made wrong ?

Comment: Download the PDF file and open it in a text editor (like notepad).  See if anything is even in there.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't suggest manually building emails like you are.  I'd suggest using a pre-made library to do this for you.

Comment: Got just file name nothing alse

Comment: How can i use that library ? @ Rocket Hazmat

Comment: To complete what @RocketHazmat suggested, I recommend you [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Check out either http://swiftmailer.org/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/  I don't know much about them, but they may be useful.  Personally, I use the CodeIgniter framework and its mail functions.

Comment: Why are you doing `base64_encode($filename)`?  Why are you base64'ing the filename.  I'd assume you'd want to encode the actual **file**.

Comment: I dont have experience i got example and i apply it . i try do what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($filename));
```

You are encoding the *filename* as your attachment.  You need to encode the actual **file** and not just its name.

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
```